# Receiving files form PLUpload in WICKET

Tags: ajax, file-upload, wicket, plupload

Im trying to integrate PLUpload into my wicket application. First steps are looking clear. Im able to choose files and when i click the "upload"-button i receive an request on server-side in my `PLUploadBehavior` based on `AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior`. **But it does not seems to be a MultiPart request.**

`public abstract class PLUploadBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {`

```
public PLUploadBehavior() {

}

@Override
public void renderHead(final Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(component, response);
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(new JavaScriptResourceReference(PLUploadBehavior.class, "plupload.full.min.js"));


    StringBuffer script = new StringBuffer();
    //build the init-script...
    response.render(OnLoadHeaderItem.forScript(script.toString()));
}

@Override
protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    Request request = getComponent().getRequest();
    //received request here, but don't know hot to access files

    if (request instanceof IMultipartWebRequest) {
        System.out.println("Multipart!!!");
    }
}

}
```

I followed the tutorial for plupload and have no form in my html template. There is none in the [tutorial](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Getting-Started), so i think i don't need it. Anyone an idea to access the files on server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more coffee i found the solution to my problem. The example on [wicket in action](http://wicketinaction.com/2012/11/uploading-files-to-wicket-iresource) can get adapted to the use with an Behavior. Thanks to Martin Grigorov and the great Wicket Team!